# Perfect Square Number, prime

Tags: number-theory

I want to show that $p^{p+1}+(p+1)^p$ is not perfect square number. ($p$ is prime number)

This is what I do

Assume $p^{p+1}+(p+1)^p=k^2$.

$(p+1)^p=(k+p^{\frac {p+1} 2})(k-p^{\frac {p+1} 2})$.

Let $2ab=p+1, gcd(a,b)=1$.

$k+p^{\frac {p+1} 2}=2^{p-1}a^{p}, k-p^{\frac {p+1} 2}=2b^p$.

Therefore $p^{\frac {p+1} 2}=|2^{p-2}a^p-b^p|$.

By Fermat's little theorem, $a\equiv 2b \pmod{p}$, and $2ab=p+1$, so $a=2b$. In this case I can show contradiction.

but, if $a=1$ I don't know how show contradiction.

Comment: @adola Every $p+\frac12$ should be $\frac{p+1}2$ instead.

Comment: A) IMO The "Let $2ab=p+1$" part might be written backwards (in terms of the flow of the proof). You should first show that $\gcd(k+.., k-..) = 1$ or 2, then proceed with cases. B) You only dealt with 1 case, and should consider the other 3 cases (e.g. $k+... = a^p, ak...=b^p$).

Comment: thank you for edit. I don't know how enter math in internet.

Comment: C) I'm not sure how you concluded that $ a = 2b$. In fact, we have $ a \equiv 2b \equiv \pm 1$, and from there can conclude that $ a = 1, 2b = p+1$.

Comment: to Calvin Lin. gcd(k+..,k-...) must be 2, because p=2 is not correct, and so p is odd prime. so k is odd number. so k+... and k-... are even number.

Comment: to Calvin Lin. 2ab=p+1 so a and b is below (p+1)/2. and a=2b(mod p) so we can conclude a=2b or a=1, 2b=p+1. I can show case1(a=2b) is contradiction. but I don't know a=1, 2b=p+1....

Comment: I can only respond to what I see in front of me, and whatever additional effort I'm willing to put in. You may be thinking it, but I (and most others here) are not mind readers. IMO What you wrote should have been in the question. D) Noted, I didn't work that far to eliminate gcd = 1. E) So from $a\equiv 2b$, we get that $ a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ so $ a\equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$. We can eliminate $a \equiv -1$, which just leaves $ a = 1, 2b = p+1$.

Comment: F) You might want to clarify what you're asking for here. I'm not sure if that's a translation issue. IE Are you asking for help with the case of $ a =1, 2b = p+1$? are you asking for a solution verification?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Originally, it was p+1/2. It's the OP's fault.

Comment: sorry my English is bad. I ask for help with the case of a=1, 2b=p+1. Honestly I didn't write every process in this page. because writing here is so hard to me. I think just this will be enough to ask help for a=1, 2b=p+1.

Comment: @Matholic English is not a very big problem here.. we have grammarians in here as well (:D).

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is quite faulty (mathematically speaking, you omitted 2-3 cases i think), so I will reweite it entirely.

$$p^{p+1}+(p+1)^p=k^2\Leftrightarrow (p+1)^p=\big(k-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\big)\big(k+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\big)$$

Notice that $\text{gcd}(p+1;p)=1$ and $\text{gcd}\big(k-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}};k+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\big)|2\cdotp^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$, thus leading to $$\text{gcd}\big(k-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}};k+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\big)|2$$

$(p+1)^p$ is even so at least one of $k-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$ and $k+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$ is even, thus $$\text{gcd}\big(k-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}};k+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\big)=2$$

Note that case $p=2$ does not work, so from now on we will only work with $p\geq 3$

We can now safely assume that we have $2$ cases:

$1)$ $k-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}=2\cdot a^p$ and $k+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}=2^{p-1}\cdot b^p$ with $2ab=p+1$

$2)$ $k-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}=2^{p-1}\cdot a^p$ and $k+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}=2\cdot b^p$ with $2ab=p+1$

(notice that $a$ abd $b$ are not divisible by $p$)

---

Case $1)$: Using Fermat's little theorem, we get $k\equiv2a\pmod{p}$ and $k\equiv b\pmod{p}$ so $2a\equiv b\pmod{p}$ but $2ab\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ so either $b=1$ and $a=\frac{p+1}{2}$ or $b=p-1$ and $a=\frac{p+1}{2(p-1)}$.

Clearly when $a=\frac{p+1}{2(p-1)}$ we get a contradiction (unless $p=3$, which is a special case, we can easily see that $4^3+3^4$ is not a perfect square)

So $b=1$ and $a=\frac{p+1}{2}$ But $k=2^{p-1}b^p-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$ so if $b=1$ then $2^{p-1}> p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$ which is clearly false for all primes $p$.

So we only get contradictions in this case.

---

Case $2):$ Again, using the same method we get $2b\equiv a\pmod{p}$ so with the same reasoning $a=1$ and $b=\frac{p+1}{2}$

We know $k=2\cdot a^p+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}=2^{p-1}\cdot b^p-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$ so we get $$2+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}=2^{p-1}\cdot \big(\frac{p+1}{2}\big)^p-p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}$$ which can we rewritten as $$2(1+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}})=2^{p-1}\cdot \big(\frac{p+1}{2}\big)^p$$

We assumed $p\geq 3$ so $p\equiv 1$ or $3\pmod{4}$

If $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $1+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ so $$v_2(2(1+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}})=2$$ but $$v_2(2(1+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}})=v_2(2^{p-1}\cdot \big(\frac{p+1}{2}\big)^p)\geq p-1$$ giving us $$3\geq p$$ so contradiction; we assumed $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$

If $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ then $\frac{p+1}{2}$ is even, so $p^\frac{p+1}{2}\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ (any odd perfect square is $1\pmod{4}$) so we have again that $1+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}}\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ so $$v_2(2(1+p^{\frac{p+1}{2}})=2$$ giving us the same result, $3\geq p$, which would lead to $p=3$, which we established is a contradiction.

---

Thus, there is no prime $p$ for which $p^{p+1}+(p+1)^p$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Nitpickery: if $p=2$ then your initial hypothesized factorization into $(k\pm p^{(p+1)/2})$ isn't possible (since you don't have a difference-of-squares in the first place), so you can't really imply the contradiction that you do further down. Instead I think you just want to handle that case by explicit calculation.

Comment: True, true, I am editing it in. Sorry for the bad proof-writing

Comment: It is now fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will study your proof and if I have more question(If I can't understand) about your proof, I'll add comment

Comment: Hi. in case 2) I think $ k=2^{p-1}+p^{p+1/2}=2(p+1/2)^{p}-p^{p+1/2} $ is right. isn't it?

Comment: Or... in case 2) is using 1) and not $ b^{2}==1(mod p) $ but $ 4a^{2}==1(mod p).$..?

Comment: if this is right.. you skip proof about 2)?? @Vlad

Comment: i tried again... um... $4a^{2}==1 (mod p) $ is same conclution in case 1).. And so in case2) k is wrong, I think. If I fix that, I get $ p^{(p+1)/2}=((p+1)/2)^{p}-2^{p-2}$ and still I don't know how I get contradiction... please help me.